# Can importlib import a module from any directory (non-packages)?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I am trying to import python files programmatically using `importlib`.

For instance, given a file "a/b/some_file.py", and given also there are no `__init__.py` files in any of those directories (nor can I add them), what is the best way to import it?

What I tried doesn't seem like it's correct:
(After lunching the prompt from "a"'a parent directory and adding it to the path)

```
 >>> importlib.import_module('a.b.some_file')
ImportError: No module named a.b.some_file
```

I also tried a relative import but the result is the same.